# how to change my pie chart color according to the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, highcharts

i want to show color red when  View Bag = Inactive, I'm using high charts to show pie chart. while status is active it should be in default or blue , when its status is Inactive it should be in red color

[image]

code

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Transformers status'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name} <b>{}</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name} @ViewBag.status</b> {}',
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: '@ViewBag.status',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'FP N-67.7',
      y: 1,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Hi krishna mohan, How does status work? Does it change dynamically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41747552/2742156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question, there can be two approaches:

1. if the active-inactive flag is **static ( i.e. once screen is loaded it wont change)**

you can set the color attribute onload of the document:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
      colors: ['#ff0000']
});
```

2. if flag can change on **some event after loading:** in this case you can use the chart variable to change the color of the graph.

   chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({ fill: '#ff0000' });

I have tried to cover both the use cases in below example. Hope this helps

```js
$(function() {
  if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == 'inactive') {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      colors: ['#ff0000']
    });
  }
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
          ['Chrome', 75]
        ]
      }]
    });
  });
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var radioValue = $("input[name='status']:checked").val();
    if (radioValue == 'inactive') {
      chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
        fill: '#ff0000'
      });
    } else {
      chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
        fill: '#2f7ed8'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<label><input type="radio" name="status" value="active">Active</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="status" value="inactive" checked>In-Active</label>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```